# Passing variable to another class with dependent parameters

Tags: python, django, box-api

I am trying to pass `access_token` variable from one class to another in Django. Here is the code:

```
def select(request):

    code = request.REQUEST.get('code')
    response = finish_authenticate_v2(client_id, client_secret, code)
    access_token = str(response['access_token'])

    return render_to_response(context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def final(request):
    token = select(request)
    access_token = token.access_token

    return render_to_response(context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I am getting an error:

```
Missing parameter. "code" is required
```

because the `code` in `select()` is obtained from the url when in the `select` webpage, but there is no `code` to grab when on the `final` url. Is there a way to pass the `code` so that I can pass have access to the `access_token`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see how [sessions are used in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/), a good usage example can also be seen at the [django.auth module](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py)

```
def select(request):
    ...
    request.session['access_token'] = str(response['access_token'])
    ...

def final(request):
    access_token = request.session['access_token']
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll read up on those documents you provided as well.